# How to show that $⟨a,b | aba=bab⟩$ is not the trivial group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show that G =  $⟨a,b | aba=bab⟩$  is not the trivial group

I tried to find homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $\mathbb Z$ which maps $a$ to $0$ and $b$ to $1$ (or $b$ to $0$ and $a$ to $1$) and if such a homomorphism exists , 
$\phi(b)$ is non-trivial and thus  b is non-trivial.
but I didn't found  such a homomorphism.

I'm also tried to conclude it directly from the relation and I failed again

Thanks

Comment: If you add the relation $ab=ba$ then you quickly deduce $a=b$, so there is a surjective map to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You can define your homomorphism to ${\mathbb Z}$ by mapping $a$ and $b$ to $1$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\mathbb Z$ satisfies this, with $a=b$.

Phrased differently, adding the relation $ab=ba$ we quickly deduce that $a=b$, so the new relation gives a surjective map to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Also $S_3$ with $a=(1\ 2)$ and $b=(2\ 3)$.

Comment: @lulu OK, so we can "extend" $G$ with another relation and get a presentaion of $Z$ , can you please explain how this helps in my case ? Tnx

Comment: If a set surjects onto an infinite set, it is obviously infinite.

Comment: @r.p. when you add another relation you are not extending $G$ but actually taking a quotient.

Answer (score 1):

The deficiency of a finite presentation $<X|R>$ is defined to be $|X|-|R|$. If $\operatorname{def}(G)>0$ then group $G$ is of order infinite.